# How to check weather UIWebView is used in project or not and to replace it WKWebView on windows platorm

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, webview, wkwebview

While uploading app, I got this from apple,

> TMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting
>   submissions of new apps that use UIWebView APIs starting from April
>   2020. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

I tried searching for the "UIWebView" in the project search option in vs code but no luck, but there is 'react-native-web' is used in the application.
Could this (react-native-web) be the reason for getting a warning?
And if some other component is using webView how could I identify it?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

PS: Solution for windows is having high priority as I am on windows and don't have a mac system accessible right now, or else answers for any OS are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have two projects with both WKWebView and UIWebView and when I do a text search of "UIWebView" on the project I know that have UIWebView it gives me results from these directories:

- /node_modules/cordova-ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Private/Plugins/CDVUIWebViewEngine
- /node_modules/cordova-ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public

Also I believe this is the headers file for cordova-ios module and it imports UIWebView with the following expression:

- /node_modules/cordova-ios/CordovaLib/Cordova/Cordova.h

```
 #import <Cordova/CDVUIWebViewDelegate.h
```